# IBM MQ remove unwanted data

Tags: ibm-mq

Could anyone explain how can we reduce total message data send to a topic, like unnecessary message headers. I am trying to send a string of message to a topic and retrieve from that topic using an MQGET call. https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=calls-mqget-get-message as defined in this link, datalength is the total size of message received from the topic. The difference of datalength and actual string size is very different. datalength is much more higher than the actual string I am sending.

So it must be that IBM MQ is padding the message with headers and properties which are not required for just sending a string to a topic.

Can we disable the unused headers and properties so that the datalength can come down?

EDIT:

Publisher's side code. here protomsg is the google's protobuf.

```
string buffer;   // message buffer  

protomsg.SerializeToString(&buffer);
long n =buffer.length();
char *char_array;
char_array = &buffer[0];
            MQPUT(Hcon,       
                  Hobj,      
                  &md,        
                  &pmo,       
                   n,
                  char_array, 
                  &CompCode,  
                  &Reason);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MQGMO properties options to control which properties are included and whether the properties are returned as message headers or in a separate message handle.
You might want to set the MQGMO_NO_PROPERTIES option, documented here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=mqgmo-options-mqlong

Comment: after adding no properties option also there is a significant difference between sending a large message and sending the same message in pieces in different messages. like in the multiple of 10. is it supposed to be that way for multiple msgs?

Comment: Every MQ message has meta data about the message stored in the MQMD (MQ Message Descriptor), you can not turn this off.

Comment: @JoshMc does the MQMD data gets counted in the datalength field of MQGET?

Comment: @JoshMc like for example I have a payload which is of 2585001 (datalength value) when I send the whole payload in a single message. but when I cut it in 50 messages and send those messages I get a total value of 65917550bytes (datalength value). is it possible that IBM adds that much metadata and message descriptors to each message?

Comment: That sounds like you are allocating a large message buffer rather than one the size of your actual payload.  What language are you using? Can you post in your question a sample that reproduces the same situation.

Comment: @JoshMc I have added the code in the question for the subscriber, is it the one here creating the problem or is it on the publishers side?

Comment: My guess would be that it is the side which is is putting the message to the queue or topic.  If it specifies a bufflen larger than the actual message it will transmit all of that data as the message body and that becomes the DataLength returned to the MQGET call.

Comment: @JoshMc I have added the publisher's side code to the question

Comment: You should be comparing 'n' in the publisher code to datalength from the MQGET. SerializeToString(...) may change the length.
Also your string length maybe in characters but each character may be more than one byte in length for some codepages

Comment: @Rich but then why would it matter only when I cut the message in pieces before sending. For consideration say I have a sub-stucture in the protomsg which allows me to set values to it and therefore split the data payload. When I have a single message and there are many substructures (more size in bytes), and when I have 50 or 100 msgs and substructures inside each message is less but the total data is same, then the SerializeToString function changes in the size should not matter as it's only like splitting single message into multiple messages.

Comment: The way to see how much data MQ is adding is to compare 'n' in your publisher code to DataLength in your subscriber code for a single message. Doing that will allow you to be consistent in what you are comparing.

Comment: The comment monster ate the first half of my previous comment! If you SerializeToString and then split the resulting flat buffer into multiple MQ messages then it looks like MQ is adding all the extra data. If you split the structured data before converting each piece with SerializeToString, then the total number of bytes for all the buffers may be higher. This is something you can test by comparing 'n' and DataLength for each message sent.